# How do you create a Double Array from an Object Array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

For example if i have 30 runner objects which all have a `getTime` method.  How can I do something like `runner[index ].getTime() = new Double Array`?

Comment: Could you please paste the code for the `getTime` method? Knowing the return type for whatever it is that you want to convert to a double array would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple loop would do

```
double[] times = new double[runner.length];
for(int i=0; i<runner.length; i++) {
  times[i] = runner[i].getTime();
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  if i also had a runnerName method and needed to sort runners by runnerTime and runnerName, how would i associate runnerTime with runnerName? Im not even sure if my original question would help me solve that problem.  Any pointers?

Comment: Again, you really need to post some code here. It's hard to figure out what you are saying simply from your description. We need to see some code. And I believe it's a better idea to create a new post for extra questions.

Answer (score 1):

There's no shortcut. You allocate the new array and you do the loop, assigning the relevant property / method call value from the objects in the old array to the corresponding entry in the new array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick way to do this. You will have to create a new `Double` array, and then iterate over your original array while populating the new one with the corresponding value from the first array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < runners.length; i++) {
    times[i] = runners[i].getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a functional approach. Use `Collection` instead of arrays and use Google Guava's [transform function](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double[] convertToDouble(type[] runner){
    double[] timeArray = new double[runner.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < runner.length; i++){
        timeArray[i] = runner[i].getTime();
    }
    return timeArray;
}
```

I'm not sure what your `type` is for the input array, so change the `type[]` to the type you need. But a static method like the above should work.

Its use:

```
convertToDouble(runner);
```

EDIT: Please paste the relevant code pieces you have. This may not work, and I'm confused as to what your input to the function is. Is it an array? Is it not an array? Knowing that would allow us to help you better.

Comment: So... What's up? Is the code working? Any thoughts? Feedback? Questions?

Comment: I need to get back to my computer but ill let you know. Thanks!